# Image stuck on page 2 - CSS Print

Tags: html, css, printing

I added a custom control to a .NET page which allows user to upload a picture.
This control has a div element which parents an image that is supposed to get printed. The control is positioned near the bottom of the HTML structure and therefore the image gets printed on page two.

However the problem is that I want the picture to get printed on page **one** but no matter what I try the picture never gets there. I've tried absolute positioning and floating.

Now what to do, what to do? :)

**Update:**

The HTML page includes many forms and stuff so it's difficult to give code examples but here's what it basically looks like:

```
<div class="col">Bunch of stuff</div> // Left column
<div class="col">Bunch of stuff + the image control</div> // Right column
```

When print; the columns are stacked upon each other by using float, but I want the image element to be positioned **on top of page one**.

Comment: Could you provide some code/sample? Please note that HTML is not a page description language, so it's very complicated to create the same results on every browser.

Comment: @Zeta I edited the post and added a sample

Comment: I went another way with this problem. I moved the image to the top of the HTML structure and positioned it absolute since the other way seems to be a problem.

Comment: If you solved this problem, [please answer it and accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't figure out a solution for this problem, I ended up with restructuring the HTML so that the "image control" was at the top. Then I was able to position the control at the top of the printed page.